# Javascript Math.pow(10, -x) Unexpected Result

Tags: javascript

When using [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) in Javascript, I am getting unexpected result. See my experiments. Used Chrome V: 79.0.3945.130, Console to get these results:

`Math.pow(10, -1)` Expected: `0.1`, Result: `0.1`

`Math.pow(10, -2)` Expected: `00.1`, Result: `00.1`

`Math.pow(10, -3)` Expected: `000.1`, Result: `000.1`

`Math.pow(10, -4)` Expected: `0000.1`, **Result: `0.00009999999999999999`**

`Math.pow(10, -5)` Expected: `00000.1`, **Result: `0.000009999999999999999`**

`Math.pow(10, -6)` Expected: `000000.1`, Result: `000000.1`

[image]

The case of -4 and -5 is making this unusable for me for the reason I wanted to use it. (offsetting numbers with a set decimal length for display)

Any way to ensure the "expected" behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I am using Firefox V72 and there is no such issue

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
Math.pow(10,-4).toFixed(4)
Math.pow(10,-5).toFixed(5)
```

```js
console.log(Math.pow(10, -2).toFixed(2))
console.log(Math.pow(10, -3).toFixed(3))
console.log(Math.pow(10, -4).toFixed(4))
console.log(Math.pow(10, -5).toFixed(5))
console.log(Math.pow(10, -6).toFixed(6))

let number = -7
console.log(Math.pow(10, number).toFixed(Math.abs(number)))
```

Comment: Note that the data type will change to string instead of floating value.